# Is it wrong to say "the lesser of the two evils"?

Tags: idioms

Is it wrong to say "the lesser of the two evils" as opposed to "the lesser of two evils"?

Comment: This will depend on context, the latter is the more usual form but the first is not incorrect.

Comment: Just don't say *the lesser of the two weevils* ([YouTube link](https://youtu.be/Y-aPp7Kiiyg))

Comment: @Clare - Unless you're Master and Commander.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "the" implies that the evils are quantified so in my opinion, you would have had to specifically mention the two evils before you could say "the lesser of the two evils is X". Being an idiom, the matter of common usage comes into play and "the lesser of two evils" is more common parlance.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I do not understand "quantified" in this context. Is it meant to denote "previously specified"?